# What is the optimal RDBMS solution for large social networking sites like Facebook?

Tags: database, facebook, social-networking

I found out two possible solutions for implementing the database structure for social networking sites like Facebook.

1.: Creating a 'Relationships' table and inserting every friendship into it. For example: user A adds B as friend (A-B), then the logic puts (A-B) and (B-A) into the 'Relationships' table. Then it indexes the first attribute.

2.: Creating a unique table for all the users containing friends. Most databases work with nearly 2 billion unique tables, so it won't be a problem; however, the database size will be nearly 300 times bigger (expecting 300 friends average per user). In this scenario, querying friends would not be a problem (as simple as SELECT * FROM)

Any ideas? Am I wrong somewhere?
Thanks all.

Comment: oh, forgot to mention: I looked for answers how to implement it, and I found out that they do not use RDBMS at all for implementing the data structure. But implementing in an RDBMS way would be still interesting.

Comment: AFAIK, Facebook *do* use MySQL, but still you might want to consider using a graph database instead. Example: http://neo4j.org/

Comment: The RDBMS solution is the first one.  Adding additional tables, one for each data item, is not in the approach.  Table names, in every SQL implementation I've seen, were not convenient to manipulate as if they were data entries.

Comment: Yes, I read message queue for Twitter, not for Facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table-per-user solution that you are describing sounds basically like Oracle's partitions feature.

Not exactly related, but I recommend this awesome post: [Presentation Summary “High Performance at Massive Scale: Lessons Learned at Facebook”](http://idleprocess.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/presentation-summary-high-performance-at-massive-scale-lessons-learned-at-facebook/)

I think that the friendships table is the least of their concerns :)

Comment: There's an excellent article here on structuring a database for the social graph: http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2009/09/07/graphs-in-the-database-sql-meets-social-networks/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about maximum table size and stuff like that. In order to create a site like Facebook you have to shard/partition all your tables to multiple machines anyway.